# Read large number of .h5 datasets

Tags: matlab

I'm working with these h5 files that have tens of thousands of datasets that contains vectors of numerical values and all of the same size. My goal is to read the datasets and create one large matrix from these vectors. The datasets are named from "0" to "xxxxx" (some large number) I was able to read them and get the matrix but it takes forever to do so. I was wondering if you can take a look at my code and suggest a way to make it run faster
here is how I do it right now

```
t =[];
for i = 0:40400 % there are 40401 datasets in this particular file
   j =  int2str(i); 
   p = '/mesh/';  % The parent group
   s = strcat(p,j);  % to create the full path of a dataset e.g. '/mesh/0'
   r = h5read('temp.h5',s);  % the file name is temp and s has the dataset path  
   t = [t;r];
end
```

in this particular case, there are 40401 datasets, each has 80802x1 vector of numerical values. Therefore eventually I want to create 80802x40401 matrix. This code takes over a day to finish. I think one of the reason it is slow because in every iteration, matlab access the h5 file. I would appreciate it if some of you have some tips in speeding up the code

Comment: Something I don't get: If you do `t = [t;r];` wouldn't the vectors `r` be stacked one above the other to get a big vector, instead of having a big matrix of vectors one alongside the other?

Answer (score 0):

When I copied you code in an editor, I get the red tilde under the `t` with the warning:

> The variable `t` appears to change size on every loop iteration. Consider preallocating for speed.

[image: speed]

You should allocate the final memory of t before starting the loop, with the function `zeros`:

```
t = zeros(80804,40401);
```

You should also read this: [Programming Patterns: Maximizing Code Performance by Optimizing Memory Access](https://fr.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/programming-patterns-maximizing-code-performance-by-optimizing-memory-access.html):

- **Preallocate arrays before accessing them within loops**
- Store and access data in columns
- **Avoid creating unnecessary variables**

Maybe `p = '/mesh/';` is useless inside the loop and can be done outside the loop, since it doesn't change. It could be even better to not have `p` and directly do `s = strcat('/mesh/',j);`